# FreeBSD disk parts with no mounting. How does this work?

Tags: configuration, freebsd, diskpart

I'm using a VPS service. I installed FreeBSD 8.1, and now configuring.
And today, I found really wired thing. 
This is my disklabel editor screen from `sysinstall`.

```
                         FreeBSD Disklabel Editor

Disk: ad0       Partition name: ad0s1   Free: 0 blocks (0MB)

Part      Mount          Size Newfs   Part      Mount          Size Newfs
----      -----          ---- -----   ----      -----          ---- -----
ad0s1a    <none>        512MB *
ad0s1b    swap          987MB SWAP
ad0s1d    <none>       1517MB *
ad0s1e    <none>        512MB *
ad0s1f    <none>      16951MB *






The following commands are valid here (upper or lower case):
C = Create        D = Delete   M = Mount pt.            W = Write
N = Newfs Opts    Q = Finish   S = Toggle SoftUpdates   Z = Custom Newfs
T = Toggle Newfs  U = Undo     A = Auto Defaults        R = Delete+Merge

Use F1 or ? to get more help, arrow keys to select.
```

`sysinstall` run from running FreeBSD box. This is not installing. I can't understand how is  this working now! I even installed some packages!

```
%pkg_info
ca_root_nss-3.12.4  The root certificate bundle from the Mozilla Project
curl-7.20.1         Non-interactive tool to get files from FTP, GOPHER, HTTP(S)
gettext-0.18_1      GNU gettext package
gmake-3.81_4        GNU version of 'make' utility
gmp-5.0.1           A free library for arbitrary precision arithmetic
libiconv-1.13.1_1   A character set conversion library
perl-5.10.1_1       Practical Extraction and Report Language
sudo-1.7.3          Allow others to run commands as root
%
```

I don't know hardware configuration of my VPS service. Is this normal? Please explain this to me how it's working now, and how should I handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sysinstall's disklabel editor does not read `/etc/fstab`, so it cann't show you current mountpoints. Sysinstall is fairly ugly and works good only for initial installation, so better forget about it after installation. Read [handbook](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/mount-unmount.html) if you want to know how change mountpoints without sysinstall.

Comment: The parts are mounted well in `fstab`. Can I assume all settings are well done?

Comment: Yes, if all needed filesystems are properly mounted